# ButtonTestSFML - Button clicked state

Tags: c++, user-interface, github, sfml

I have a minor problem in my code and can't resolve it.
I created a Button class using SFML library. Its just code practice since I'm relatively new to programing.

But the problem is that I can't make it work on release, it only works when pressed. So instead of one click it registers multiple clicks while it is being pressed. It's best to try the given code to see what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Here is code for Button class:

```
    class Button
{
    private:
    
        //Button Text Params:
        sf::Font font;                  
        sf::Text text;                  
        sf::Vector2f textPos;           
        sf::Vector2f textBounds;        
        //Button Shape Params:
        sf::RectangleShape shape;
        sf::Vector2f pos;               
        sf::Vector2f size;              
        //Button colors(Hover and Default)
        sf::Color DefaultColor;         
        sf::Color hColor;     
        //Button Sounds:
        sf::SoundBuffer bf1;            
        sf::SoundBuffer bf2;            
        sf::Sound HoverSound;           
        sf::Sound ClickSound;           

        bool wFocus = false;            //Returns focus on main window
        
        bool ButtonClick = false;       //Controls the code on button click
        
        bool CursorOverButton(sf::RenderWindow &window) //Detect cursor pos on window
        {
            sf::Vector2f CursorPos = (sf::Vector2f)sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);

            if((CursorPos.x < (pos.x + size.x) && CursorPos.x > pos.x) && (CursorPos.y < (pos.y + size.y) && CursorPos.y > pos.y))
            {

                if(shape.getFillColor() != hColor){     //if cursor passes over window 
                    shape.setFillColor(hColor);         //all of this will execute
                    HoverSound.play();
                }
                return true;
            }
            else 
            {
                shape.setFillColor(DefaultColor);
                return false;
            }
        }

    public:

        Button()
        {
            font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"); //Loads font for Button text default is ariel(change to what you want!)
        }
        //Button Creation:
        void create(std::string ButtonText, int TextSize,  sf::Color Color, float buttonWidth, float buttonHeight, float x, float y, sf::Color HoverColor)
        {
            //Create Button size and position:
            pos.x = x;
            pos.y = y;
            size.x = buttonWidth;
            size.y = buttonHeight;
            DefaultColor = Color;
            hColor = HoverColor;
            
            //Load text for button:
            text.setFont(font);
            text.setCharacterSize(TextSize);
            text.setString(ButtonText);
            text.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
            text.setOutlineThickness(2);
            sf::FloatRect fr =  text.getGlobalBounds();
            textBounds.x = fr.width + fr.left;
            textBounds.y = fr.height + fr.top;
            
            //Apply parameters to shape:
            shape.setSize(size);
            shape.setFillColor(DefaultColor);
            shape.setPosition(pos);
            
            //Fit text to button:
            text.setOrigin(textBounds.x/2, textBounds.y/2);
            text.setPosition(pos.x + (size.x/2), pos.y + (size.y/2) - 1);
        }
        
        
        bool isButtonClicked(sf::RenderWindow &window) //When button is pressed down whis executes
        {
            if(!CursorOverButton(window)) //Tests focus on window
            {
                wFocus = (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left))? true : false;
            }
            if(CursorOverButton(window) && !wFocus && sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left))
            {
                if(!ButtonClick) ClickSound.play(); //Plays only on first click
                ButtonClick = true;
                return true;
            }
            else ButtonClick = false; //Return clicked state
            return false;
        }

        void HoverClickSound(std::string HoverSoundPath1, std::string ClickSoundPath2) //add sounds to buffer and load into
        {                                                                              //playable sound
            bf1.loadFromFile(HoverSoundPath1);
            HoverSound.setBuffer(bf1);
            bf2.loadFromFile(ClickSoundPath2);
            ClickSound.setBuffer(bf2);
        }
        
        void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window) //draws button on window(with text)
        {
            window.draw(shape);
            if(textBounds.x < size.x || textBounds.y < size.y) window.draw(text);
        }
};
```

[Full Code with test is here on github](https://github.com/VukMar/ButtonTestSFML.git)

Comment: What do you mean by "register multiple clicks"? How did you find that? In your main function, inside the while loop, you can incrementing the counter when button is clicked. Are you talking about this counter?

Comment: Hi VukMar. It' s not a good idea to link your code in a question, but rather isolate the problematic piece of code and share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so someone can help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! I added a code sample. Full code with test is provided in the link. The problem is that the button reacts same as SFML function sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed insted of sf::Keyboard::isKeyReleased.

Answer (score 0):

So I came across a solution(for the most part) it still registers on being pressed but registers only the first initial press down, once, and doesn't execute the wanted code more then once. Say you want to increment a value by one when button is clicked it used to run the code while button is pressed multiple times(because of the refresh rate), now this part of code wont let it continue after initial press down:

```
bool isButtonClicked(sf::RenderWindow &window) //When button is pressed down whis executes
        {
            if(!CursorOverButton(window)) //Tests focus on window
            {
                wFocus = (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left))? true : false;
            }
            if(CursorOverButton(window) && !wFocus && sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left))
            {
                if(!ButtonClick)  //This wont let it execute more then once on click
                { 
                    ClickSound.play();
                    ButtonClick = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }
            else ButtonClick = false; //Return clicked state
            return false;
        }
```

Thoughts?